# Put List of strings into NSUserDefaults object

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've two ios application, first is contain app and second is today widget app.

In appdelegate class in contain app, I have List of symbols, which I want to pass with **NSUserDefaults** object, because I need to get this object in my today widget app.

My problem is that I cant store **List** of **strings** into **NsUserDefaults** object.

Object has several methods : SetBool, SetDouble, SetInt, SetString
but there is no method which can take some object.

Only one method is which is taking NSObject for value and NSString for key.

Here is my code

```
  var userSharedContent = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
            var symbols = await DatabaseManager.Instance.GetRecentCoinsAsync(5); // returns list of tuples
            var listOfStrings = symbols.Select(o => o.symbol).ToList(); // take strings for tuples and conver it to List()

            userSharedContent.SetValueForUndefinedKey()
```

How can I solve this problem and Convert List into NSobject to pass it.

What is solution ? I've stacked in this task three days already. I want to pass data from one application to another application.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` works with "native" types, so you have to do some conversions between `C#` and `ObjC` types:

#### Write an NSArray of NSString from `List<string>`:

```
var listOfStrings = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };

using (var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults)
using (var nsArray = NSArray.FromStrings(listOfStrings.ToArray()))
{
    userDefaults.SetValueForKey(nsArray, new NSString("MyAppsValues"));
    userDefaults.Synchronize();
}
```

#### Read a `List<string>` from an NSArray of NSString:

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();

using (var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults)
using (var nsArray = userDefaults.ValueForKey(new NSString("MyAppsValues")) as NSArray)
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < nsArray.Count; i++)
    {
        var cSharpStr = nsArray.GetItem<NSString>(i).ToString();
        listOfStrings.Add(cSharpStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it as soon as I will arrive at work. Thank you vey much

Comment: @TornikeGomareli no problem.